# Nvidia Problems Spreading

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, graphics

I recently received a used computer from my dad's work.  Still kind of new to the whole computer gaming but I intend to eventually plan on building a good one. My current computer from my dad had a Hynix Red graphics card but when I tried playing Team Fortress 2 I kept getting various errors.

Eventually I found that I needed a different graphics card so I got a Nvidia Geforce 210 from a friend.

The Nvidia worked at first but I was unable to play games still because it required me to update the drivers.  So I tried doing this by updating from version 304 up to 319 and after rebooting my computer to finish the update like it says to do my computers background is messed up.

The background has little black and white squares and when i try to open a window it is a  white box with an array of colors stretched around it.  The taskbar on the side: however, is fine and completely normal. Ultimately this is my current problem.

Now I'm here on a different computer because I am tired of trying to blindly fix this and hoping that some will be able to help with this issue?

Comment: Currently it is difficult to tell what you are asking specifically. Can you please be more specific?

Comment: Well basically right now I just want my screen to work.  The task bar looks fine but the background which was still the default now is black and white squares and whenever I open a window it is basically a white box with other colors stretched over it.

Comment: Have you installed the proprietary drivers? If you have, was the computer working as normal before you did?

Comment: Yes that is what started the whole problem.  After I installed the drivers I wasn't able to login after I rebooted it.

Comment: I think it was on an outdated version of nvidia 304 and i tried updating to 319 or something close to that. I know those were the numbers though if that help you any.

Comment: Okay I have reopened your question, because you gave some specifics here in the comments. If you can add this info to your question, I believe you should be able to get an answer. I have a system which uses nvidia drivers but I don't use it regularly, and it is on 12.10 or 13.04 IIRC, so I don't want to give an answer in case I could be wrong.

Comment: When you say "open a tab", what do you mean? In Firefox/Chromium or something else?

Comment: Chromium or anything else really. If I open up any window it acts the same just a different sized box

Comment: Please try to be specific when giving details :)
"Or anything else really" could be a lot of things.

Comment: Any window at all. Be it Chromium, Firefox, the Software center, anything.  It always has the same white box.

Comment: Have you tried running a 2D session?

Comment: No I have not.  I'm pretty new to ubuntu so I don't really know about many ways around problems. I can try that though and see if it helps.